# Python - Average values of numpy multidimensionnal array every specific time

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, average

I have a multidimensionnal array "test[:,:,:]" and i would like to get averaged values on the test.shape[0] dimension for every 4 "frames" i would like to keep the same dimensions of my array and substitute the 4 values by the mean value.

As example:

```
test=np.array([[[ 2.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 3.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 3.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 5.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 2.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 3.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 3.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 5.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 2.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]])        


for i in range(test.shape[0]-1,4):
    test_mean = (test[i,:,:]+test[i+1,:,:]+test[i+2,:,:]+test[i+3,:,:])/4.
```

But, i don't keep the same dimension...what is the best way to do that?

Comment: It is not very clear what you mean by "I don't keep the same dimension". So, for the (9, 2, 3) array `test`, do you want a (9, 2, 3) array as a result, a (2, 2, 3) array, or something else? We could help you best if you could explicitly add the correct result for `test_mean` for reference.

Comment: It is also a good idea to stay online for a while after posting a question. Otherwise potential answerers might move on if they can't get you to comment on requests for clarification.

Comment: As i would say, i would like to keep the  (9, 2, 3) array! Thanks ;) (& i had to go).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting `test_mean` every time. A good start is:

```
test_mean = np.zeros_like(test)
for i in xrange(test.shape[0]-4):
    test_mean[i] = test[i:i+4].mean(axis=0)
```

Here is a more efficient implementation from `scipy`:

```
from scipy.ndimage import uniform_filter1d
test_mean2 = uniform_filter1d(test, 4, axis=0)
```

Check the documentation to understand how the result is stored and what options you have to treat boundary values.